# > show dbs 2017-04-25T12:02:12.277-0400 E QUERY Error: listDatabases failed:{

Tags: mongodb

I created a one node Mongo database, everything went fine and I'm able to enter mongo shell and execute commands like "db","use test" , but that's about it , I'm not able to execute any other commands like "show dbs" or insert anything. I googled as there are lot of threads on this error with some suggesting to run rs.slaveOk() and some others asking to create user, I tried creating user as below:

```
db.createUser(
      {
        user: "okkadu",
        pwd: "abc123",
        roles: [ { role: "root", db: "test" } ]
      }
    )
```

However this also failed with below error:

> Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on test to execute command

Could someone help me out what else can I try ?, please find the copy if my config file as well:

```
  ##
  **### Basic Defaults
   ##
   port = 27017
   dbpath = /opt/mongodb/data
   logappend = true
   logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
   rest = true
   fork = true
   #bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
   pidfilepath = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.pid
   journal = true
   httpinterface = true
   storageEngine = wiredTiger
   auth=true**
```

Comment: Are you authenticating when you connect to the database?

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for responding , I haven't authenticated as I'm still trying to create user first. I just entered into shell typing mongo from binary directory.

Comment: It sounds like the database is running with 'auth' enabled, so your connection to the database will have no permissions when you connect without authenticating. Since the database user hasn't been created yet, you'll want to restart the server process without 'auth' enabled, create the database user, then restart it with 'auth'. It would probably be best if you follow the instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: Hi Im now able to login with authenticating to admin database as below: mongo --port 27017 -u "userid1" -p "sgaPwdr" --authenticationDatabase "admin", how will I be able to autheticate directly to another database like as test ? when I try this it just says unable to authenticate to test: mongo --port 27017 -u "userid1" -p "sgaPwdr" --authenticationDatabase "test"  --   Error: 18 Authentication failed.

Comment: The root database user resides within the "admin" database, so you will want to authenticate against this database while connecting to the "test" database. e.g. `mongo localhost:27017/test -u USER -p PWD --authenticationDatabase admin`